# how to use jQuery datatables with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to use ajax call to load jQuery datatable, below is my code.

I am getting error on browser-console "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**".

I want to load datatable by **DeliveryCharges** tag in ajax-response.

How to pass this particular tag as source to datatable, TIA.

**Html:**

```html
<table id="mygrid" class="mydataTable2 table table-striped display table-stroke table-responsive wordwrap" width="100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="cell-20">#</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Vehicle</th>
    <th>Mile Rate($)</th>
    <th>Flat Rate($)</th>
    <th>Pick-up Fee($)</th>
    <th>Drop-off Fee($)</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**Ajax:**

```js
$('#mygrid').dataTable({
//"bProcessing": true,
  "ajax": {
    "url": "//abcd/api/DeliveryCharges",
    "type": "GET",
    "dataType": "json",
    "async": false,
    "crossDomain": true
  },
  "Columns": [
    {"CityName": "City"},
    {"VehicleName": "Vehicle"},
    {"MileRate": "Mile Rate($)"},
    {"FlatRate": "Flat Rate($)"},
    {"PickUpFee": "Pick-up Fee($)"},
    {"DropOffFee": "Drop-off Fee($)"}
  ]
});
```

**Ajax response:**

```
<DeliveryCharge xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Ulyx.Models">
<ReturnCode>1</ReturnCode>
<ReturnMessage>Success</ReturnMessage>
<_deliverycharges>
   <DeliveryCharges>
   <CityName>New Delhi</CityName>
   <CountryName>India</CountryName>
   <DropOffFee>3.40</DropOffFee>
   <FlatMile i:nil="true"/>
   <FlatRate>5.00</FlatRate>
   <MileRate>4.20</MileRate>
   <PickUpFee>2.20</PickUpFee>
   <ReturnCode i:nil="true"/>
   <ReturnMessage i:nil="true"/>
   <StateName>Delhi</StateName>
   <VehicleName i:nil="true"/>
   </DeliveryCharges>
   <DeliveryCharges>
   <CityName>New York</CityName>
   <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
   <DropOffFee>1.00</DropOffFee>
   <FlatMile i:nil="true"/>
   <FlatRate>5.00</FlatRate>
   <MileRate>1.00</MileRate>
   <PickUpFee>1.00</PickUpFee>
   <ReturnCode i:nil="true"/>
   <ReturnMessage i:nil="true"/>
   <StateName>New York</StateName>
   <VehicleName i:nil="true"/>
   </DeliveryCharges>
</_deliverycharges>
</DeliveryCharge>
```

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "//abcd/api/DeliveryCharges",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  headers: { //WRITE IF THEIR HAVE SOME HEADER REQUEST OR DATA
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    debugger;
    BindData(data._deliverycharges);
    // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  },
  error: function (requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
    alert('Please try later!');
  }, complete: function (data) {
    $("#btnSearchPricelst").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

Comment: You're telling the ajax function that you're expecting json but you're returning xml. The json parser cannot interpret xml, of course.

Comment: but when i use simple table instead of jquery datatable its working in ajax..

Comment: Then also show that code in your question, please.

Comment: i added code @Federico..

Comment: Seems like your `BindData` function can interpret XML, but DataTables' ajax function expects the response to be JSON. You need to convert the response from XML to HTML/JSON before feeding it to DataTables.